# Website doesn't work with Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

For some reason I can't click on any of the links on my website with Windows Phone. I can scroll up and down but that's pretty much it.

https://www.hersecret.fi/

No such problems with Android or with Desktop Browsers (IE included).

What's weird is that the almost identical test site is working normally even with Windows phone.

http://demo.preview.server1.hersecret.fi/

Anyone can point me in the right direction? It's much appreciated!

Comment: Phone is Lumia 920 and I tried with IE and UC browser - same problem.

Comment: There are some HTML errors... many unclosed tags and 'Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document.'

Comment: Well it seems that the problem originates from a hidden iframe that occupies almost the whole screen. In other browsers/devices the div/iframe starts with display:none; styling so it does not interfere with browsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can see easy the issue by debugging the device with safari browser. I hope you see errors from consoles

Answer (score 0):

I see a very messy code with IE mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" ""><!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="fi-fi"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie7" lang="fi-fi"><![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie8" lang="fi-fi"><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie9" lang="fi-fi"><![endif]--><HTML 
lang="fi-fi"><HEAD>             
<META charset="utf-8">             <TITLE>Naisten vaatteet netistä - 
HerSecret.fi</TITLE>                         
<META name="description" content="HerSecret.fi tarjoaa näyttävimmät bilevaatteet, leggingsit, alus-, uima- ja rooliasut, asusteet sekä korsetit. Aina ilmainen ja nopea toimitus - 2-4 arkipäivässä!"> 

<META name="keywords" content="hersecret, hersecret.fi, bilevaatteet, leggingsit, alusasut, rooliasut, korsetit, uima-asut, juhlahansikkaat, tiara, vaatekauppa, nuorten vaatekauppa, legginsit, bikinit, asusteet, naisten vaatekauppa, nettikauppa, naisten vaatekauppa netissä">
```

Many duplicated tags, all tags uppercase, etc... You can simulate it with IE/Edge developer tools